# Are my gas stove burners clicking due to high elevation?

Tags: equipment, stove, gas, high-altitude

I have a Viking gas stove. My front burners make a clicking sound when it is set on low. It doesn't seem to do this when the gas is higher. I have had a certified technician to check to see if anything is wrong and they can't seem to find anything. I have been told that this may be due to the high elevation of Calgary. We are at over 3000 feet from sea level. Could this be true?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a wolf cooktop and experience the same problem occasionally on low on certain burners. It's usually on the larger burners, and doesn't happen on the simmer settings (which is a separate burner, as they are double stacked). I always just assumed it's a pressure thing and usually just switch to a smaller burner. I am also in Calgary. I'm very interested if you find an answer. Please come back and post an answer if your gas guy suggests something that isn't suggested here!

Answer (score 2):

While trying to find other resources for you question (looking at the effect of elevation on pilot lights in furnaces, hot water heaters, etc) it was mentioned that elevation does in fact play a role in the pressure of the gas being ignited and could theoretically create a problem. In most responses though, there was debate about whether the theoretical effect was effective.

Anyway, while elevation could be causing the difficulty, if your furnace and water heater are working I might suggest that either the pilot or the burner might need a bit of cleaning. Pilots will frequently tick when they are clogged or the jets around it are not making a whole circle.

If you clean it and have no result, you might want to look into ways to increase the pressure of the gas jets without increasing the overall output. Perhaps this is one of the Vikings with sealed burners? There are varying reviews on whether this helps/hurts air to fuel ratio at higher altitudes|elevations. If this is the case, your gas company may be of some assistance.

Comment: Hi yes cleaning is helpful prob is I had a professional gas guy out and with everything clean, etc he couldn't figure out why they click other than the elevation explaination which seems somewhat logical however my friends gas range doesn't click and they don't live that far away. Just up the hill. Maybe their elevation makes a difference! My neighbour is a professional gas guy, maybe I'll see what he says/sugests. Thanks for your comments.